# Converting a GWT web app on app engine to android app

Tags: android, gwt, google-bigquery, gwt-rpc

I have a GWT App deployed on Google App Engine that makes use of RPC Calls to function.It uses Bigquery Cloud as a backend for database operations.How can i create an android app from existing google app or do i have to code again to build a native android app for this application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) and [GWT-Phonegap](https://github.com/mgwt/gwtphonegap) to create apps for Android and iOS.

Comment: Can mgwt and phonegap can assist me in porting the current web app on google app engine to an android app.Or i need to code from the scratch using both ??

Comment: You can port an existing app. mgwt makes it easier to handle various touch events, though. So you can create mobile-optimized implementations of your views/widgets replacing some of GWT widgets with mgwt widgets so you can use TapHandler instead of ClickHandler, for example. Then GWT will compile a desktop version of your app and a mobile version. With mgwt you can even create a different tablet and phone implementations, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

if RPC is your problem, you can use GWT-P REST to change your RPC in REST-FULL service. You need to refactoring your GWT client code and Server code. I had ever use in project GWT-P rest with an SPRING-REST on server side, that's work well. This can solve the problem's of RPC and serialization policy from GWT.

If you want to use the client code from gwt and use this in android Application, your only choice is to use phonegap and MGWT to create responsive design, but you must separate you server code and client code in three differents module with maven (client - server - DTO).

In first if i was at your place, i will transform my RPC service in REST-FULL service. 
After if your application is only to android and not too complexe, i advise to create an Native App android. MGWT + PHONEGAP + GWTP is more to create mobile cross-platform application.

Comment: ndaussy, yeah the app is actually complex and building it as a native app would be an added overhead.Thanks for your suggestions, do i have to make any special considerations regarding Bigquery , which is a cloud service, i mean any suggestions on integrating it on Google Cloud end points